# Android NDK: unable to open database file using sqlite3_open

Tags: c++, sqlite, android-ndk

I need to do database operations from C++ layer using ndk in Android.

but while opening database using sqlite3_open, I am getting "unable to open database file" error.

I am getting database path in Java using:

```
String sqliteDir = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("MyDb").getPath();
```

C++ code:

```
int rc = sqlite3_open(dbPath, _db);
if(rc != SQLITE3_OK) LOGD("Can't open database: %s with path %s\n", KSqlite3::sqlite3_errmsg(_db), dbPath);
else LOGD(" Opened database successfully %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := myMod
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myMod.cpp sqlite3.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
#Includes various C++ libraries
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Error Message:
**Can't open database: unable to open database file with path /data/data/com.packageName/databases/MyDb**

Comment: Does the path really lack the initial `/`?

Comment: Where'd RSSFeed come from?

Comment: Edited with proper error message

Comment: Check if `com.packageName/databases/` exists. I don't think `getDatabasePath()` creates it if it's not there.

Comment: Yes that was the only problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Seva Alekseyev, problem was I wrongly assumed that sqlite3_open will create whole path if it doesn't exists but it doesn't. So I need to create /databases manually.
Instead of getting databases directory like this:

```
String sqliteDir = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("MyDb").getPath();
```

I got it till databases:

```
String sqliteDir = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";
```

Now in cpp code before calling sqlite3_open, check if it is there.

```
struct stat sb;
int32_t res = stat(path, &sb);
if (0 == res && (sb.st_mode & S_IFDIR)){
    LOGD("Database already exists in path:%s", path);
}else{
    LOGD("Creating database path:%s", path);
    int status = mkdir(path, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH);
    if(status != 0){
        LOGD("Error occurred while creating database path : %s", path);
        return;
    }
}
string dbPath = string(path) + "//MyDb";
```

and then proceed with normal code:

```
int rc = sqlite3_open(dbPath, _db);
if(rc != SQLITE3_OK) LOGD("Can't open database: %s with path %s\n", KSqlite3::sqlite3_errmsg(_db), dbPath);
else LOGD(" Opened database successfully %s \n", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
```

Comment: Hello.  I have similar problem.  I need to open DB with c in android app.  I'm developing .so library.  How can I get packagename of the app using my library in natvie c layer?